# consider h:M(2)->R is defined by the matrix [a b c d] =(c+b,a) is h injective, surjective, both, or none?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

consider h:M(2)->R is defined by the matrix [a b  =(c+b,a) is h injective, surjective, both, or none?        c d]

Comment: Its linear algebra. How is the mapping defined?

Comment: It is either $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ as codomain of $\;h\;$ , or else you mean $\;h\;$ is a function from all the $\;2\times2\;$ matrices to **subsets** of $\;\Bbb R\;$ . Which one is it??

Comment: BTW, your question has nothing to do with modules and less with injjective ones.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you have a function $\;h:M_2(\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R^2\;$ defined as

$$h\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}:=\binom{b+c}a$$

But then

$$h\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=h\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\binom10$$

so $\;h\;$ isn't injective. It is though surjective, since for any $\;\binom xy\in\Bbb R^2\;$ , we have

$$h\begin{pmatrix}y&x\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\binom xy$$